# Please explian about HDFS Federation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can someone pls explain the highlighted lines in detail.

> Under federation, each namenode manages a **namespace volume**, which is made up of the
>   metadata for the namespace, and a **block pool** containing all the blocks for the files in the namespace. Namespace volumes are independent of each other, which means namenodes do not communicate with one another, and furthermore the failure of one namenode does not affect the availability of the namespaces managed by other namenodes. **Block pool storage** is not partitioned, however, so datanodes register with each namenode in the cluster and store blocks from **multiple block pools.**"

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of a Federated setup is like having multiple HDFS clusters, only sharing datanodes.  Each namenode keeps track of it's "namespace volume" which is a list of files and their locations.  Datanodes store files in "block pools", which can be thought of as a directory and metadata that belongs to the "namespace volume".  Block pools within a namespace volume maintain an ID to which namespace they belong to.

Block pool storage is the location local to each datanode in which data is actually written.  This could be multiple locations across different drives or a single location.  Because datanodes are 'shared' in a Federated setup, multiple block pools will be served up from these locations.

Comment: I have a question with respect to divide the storage of harddisk. Is it possible to divide the storage in Federated setup. Lets say I have two Namenode. One would be working for sales and other for marketing. Is it possible to allocate 70% of my cluster storage space to Sales and 30% to Marketing